# Table only showing first column?

Tags: jquery

Only the first column of data is showing up in table. What am i doing wrong.

And here is my code. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

```
$sResults.find("product").each(function() {
  var col1 = $(this).find('id').text();
  var col2 = $(this).find('title').text();
  var col3 = $(this).find('brand').text();
  var col4 = $(this).find('price').text();

  $('#product_table').append("<tr><td>" + col1 + "<td></td>" + col2 + "<td></td>" + col3 + "<td></td>" + col4 + "<td></td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML you generate has mis-matched opening/closing `<td>` tags. Try this:

```
$('#product_table').append("<tr><td>" + col1 + "</td><td>" + col2 + "</td><td>" + col3 + "</td><td>" + col4 + "</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<td>` elements are backwards.  You're starting the next `<td>` before closing the first.

```
$('#product_table').append("<tr><td>" + col1 + "</td><td>" + col2 + "</td><td>" + col3 + "</td><td>" + col4 + "</td></tr>");
```